# How to debug Delphi apps on Android devices?

Tags: android, delphi, debugging

With Delphi CE 10.3.3 I try to debug the sample project NativeControlsDemo on a Huawei LLD-L31 smartphone with Android 28. The app can be installed and is running. But when I mark breakpoints they are red with a cross. That means inactive. But why? The compiler and linker options for debug are enabled. Under windows the breakpoints are entered. But not when running on the smartphone. What did I miss?

Comment: Is there nobody who develops Apps for Android with Delphi? How do you debug your programs?